# Javax Validation with Maven / GWT

Tags: gwt, maven-2, vaadin, gwt-bootstrap

Im trying to use [gwtbootstrap](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap) and i implement my project the CellTables example. 
I use Vaadin 6.8.8, GWT 2.5.0 and Maven 2.2.1

Now when im trying to compile the widgeset i have this warning :

> Are validation-api-.jar and validation-api--sources.jar on the classpath?

and the this error :

> The type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Well i try all!! really many solutions from Stackoverflow and the web. From adding javax dependencies into pom.xml to adding .jar into classpath and so on.

Why gwtbootstrap seems to works with javx.validation and why i can't add javax.validation in my project?

Comment: Maybe try with Maven 3; gwt-user depends on javax.validation so they should already be there in your classpath. Now maybe it's Vaadin getting into the way.

Comment: changing to Maven 3 dont resolve it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it by using the "hard way" shows in the 5. Methods of this tutorial :

- [How to add Classpath](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

How are your dependencies on javax.validation APIs declared in Maven ? Try to change the scope of the dependency to provided, as per below; this will instruct Maven to add the dependencies to the classpath when building the application.

Make sure to read [the documentation on Maven dependency scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```